# Youtube's APi: "current time" isn't precise

Tags: javascript, numbers, youtube-api

I want to get the current time every second when the player is playing but I want it to be whole number and I never get a precice number.
Right no I am using Math.round() and Math.ceil() to fix this but then I sometimes get the same number show twice since it sometimes rounds up the number the wrong way.

```
  function checkstop() {
      if(done == true ){
        setTimeout(checkstop, 1000);
        currenttime =  player.getCurrentTime();
        $('.holderrs').html(Math.round(currenttime));
     }
  }
```

output when playing:

1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 15...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` only guarantee that `checkstop` function will be invoke `not less then` after 1000 milliseconds in your case. So, I guess, it is better to use smaller periods of time. For example:

```
var previousValue;
function checkstop() {
    if (done === true) {
        currenttime =  Math.round(player.getCurrentTime());
        if (previousValue !== currenttime) { // but set new value only if previous value is not equal new value
             previousValue = currenttime;
             $('.holderrs').html(currenttime);
        }
        setTimeout(checkstop, 100); // call after each 100 milliseconds
     }
  }
```